# Failed to create NSDictionary when reading from plist in swift 2

Tags: ios, plist

I am trying to read info from plist, ([PetList.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7jpK.png)) but I don't know why it failed. The variable path is correct, however myDict is nil, the else part is executed. What I want to do is load info form plist, then assign values to pets array.
    var pets = Pet
    func loadGameData() {

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PetList", ofType: "plist")

    let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)

    if let dict = myDict {
        //loading values
        for i in 0..<pets.count {
            pets[i].petName = dict.objectForKey("petName")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].health = dict.objectForKey("health")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].experience = dict.objectForKey("experience")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].hungry = dict.objectForKey("hungry")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].energy = dict.objectForKey("energy")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].level = dict.objectForKey("level")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].status = dict.objectForKey("status")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].searchKey = dict.objectForKey("searchKey")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].cleanliness = dict.objectForKey("cleanliness")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].isChoosed = dict.objectForKey("isChoosed")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].skill = dict.objectForKey("skill")!.absoluteString!
            pets[i].imageName = dict.objectForKey("imageName")!.absoluteString!
        }
    } else {
        print("WARNING: Couldn't create dictionary from PetList.plist! Default values will be used!")
    }
}
```

Comment: And `PetList.plist` is actually in the app bundle?

Comment: Are all values in the dictionary `NSURL` objects or what is `absoluteString` for? And apart from that you are creating `pets.count` objects with the same contents. One of the collection types must be an array.

Comment: Yes, @trojanfo this is the path I printed. /Users/Neo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1276FC11-668D-4CAC-87AE-C61141DD00E4/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/06DEB9B7-B58F-417C-8232-3F3796630F80/CandyPets.app/PetList.plist

Comment: @vadian absoluteString is used to get the string.  But myDict is nil, they would not run.

Comment: `absoluteString` is a property of the `NSURL` class to get a RFC 1808 conforming string representation of an URL. Print out `myDict`, I suspect it's not a dictionary

Comment: Do not update your question with ongoing issues.  Start a new question.  Better still use the search facility as your new issue is well documented here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

- The top level object is an array
- `absoluteString` will cause an compiler error.
- There must be a `Pet` struct or class to create instances from the array.

Something like this

```
struct Pet {
  var petName = "", health = "", experience = "", hungry = ""
  var energy = "", level = "", status = "", searchKey = ""
  var cleanliness = "", isChoosed = "", skill = "", imageName = ""
}

var pets = [Pet]()

func loadGameData() {

  let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PetList", ofType: "plist")
  if let myArray =  NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!) as? [[String:String]] {
    //loading values

    for anItem in myArray {
      var pet = Pet()
      pet.petName = anItem["petName"]!
      pet.health = anItem["health"]!
      pet.experience = anItem["experience"]!
      pet.hungry = anItem["hungry"]!
      pet.energy = anItem["energy"]!
      pet.level = anItem["level"]!
      pet.status = anItem["status"]!
      pet.searchKey = anItem["searchKey"]!
      pet.cleanliness = anItem["cleanliness"]!
      pet.isChoosed = anItem["isChoosed"]!
      pet.skill = anItem["skill"]!
      pet.imageName = anItem["imageName"]!
      pets.append(pet)
    }
  } else {
    print("WARNING: Couldn't create array from PetList.plist! Default values will be used!")
  }
}
```

Comment: It is very nice of you! Thanks!

Comment: I encounter a new problem when I try to write to plist.  fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path) return false.

Comment: In iOS you cannot write into the application bundle. Use the `Documents` directory

Comment: In addition, I would recommend that the `Pet` class implements an initializer named along the lines of: `init(withDictionary dictionary:[String : String])` so that only the `Pet` class knows the internals of the dictionary format. So the `for` loop becomes: `for anItem in myArray { var pet = Pet(withDictionary:anItem); pets.append(pet) }`

Comment: @NicolasMiari Of course, the code is just a basic example.

Comment: @far2go The logic is supposed to be: If the file does not exist, copy `PetList.plist` from the application bundle to `Documents`. If it does exist, update it.

Comment: @far2go Start a new question.  This answer is not an ongoing support call.

Comment: @trojanfoe ok, got it. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: @far2go You don't seem to have got it.  You are still asking questions that you can easily look-up yourself.  You are being a help vampire.

Comment: Sorry, I was noticed you inform after I add that comment/ So I think since I already typed that, just keep it. Now I delete it. @trojanfoe

Answer (score 0):

The top-level node of `PetList.plist` is an array, not a dictionary, which is why it's not loading.